# Can't access variable defined in Snippet from Template in Liquid

Tags: variables, shopify, liquid

I have a snippet that is included in multiple templates. It performs some operations and then defines a few variables with values based on the results of those operations. The templates then need to use those those values in a couple different ways.

It seems that I cannot access a variables defined in the snippet from the templates. A VERY watered down example:

### Sinppets/colors.liquid

```
{% assign myVar = "bar" %}
```

### templates/color-picker.liquid

```
{% assign myVar = "foo" %}
{% render 'colors' %}
{{ myVar }}
```

The output of this is `foo` while the expected output is `bar`.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, and yes, it's just not possible, at least not with `render`.

Variables declared inside of snippets called by `render` are only accessible inside of that snippet. Render has replaced `include` which is now deprecated, but allowed you to achieve what you are trying to do in the example above.

That said, you can still use `include` for now - more info here >> https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags/deprecated-tags#include

Comment: although this won't help in my particular use case, it's probably worth mentioning that you can also pass values to the Snippet with `{% render 'my-snippet',  var_for_snippet = ‘bar’ %}`